# redirect using jquery in zend framework 2

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2

I am trying to open a link "homepage/about" in a div in zend framewrok 2. The link opens successfully using the jquery script but the logic is to when the session has ended and the same link is used again it should redirect to a login page. But for me the redirect opens in the same div that is suppose to have the page "homepage/about". Below is my code for the html page:

```
<div>

  <a  id="Load" href="homepage/about">Home</a> 
  <a  href="registration">About</a>

</div>

<div class= "mainContainer" id="LoadMe">Target div</div>
```

and the jquery script is as follows:

```
<script>
  $('#Load').click(function() {
  $('#LoadMe').load($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});
</script>
```

I want the redirect to take me to the login login page rather than it opening in the target div.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example set the href via zend and do in Jquery like this:

```
$('#Load').click(function() {
  if( $(this).attr('href') == "" )
  {  
      window.location = "login.html";
  }
  else
  {
    $('#LoadMe').load($(this).attr('href'));
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ma not sure what you mean by href via zend ?

Comment: <a  id="Load" href="if userloggedin show "homepage/about" else leave it empty "" >Home</a>

Comment: how? when the user not logged is there a href?

Comment: i have this code <a    id="Load"   <?php $auth = new AuthenticationService();
                          if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {?>href="homepage/about"<?php }elseif (!$auth->hasIdentity()){?>href=""<?php }?>>Home</a> but its not working. or am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: the browser http link remains the same

Comment: No I mean to check the code in your browser when the user not logged in, I mean to check which value have the href else if alway give the same result check again your Zend code

Comment: i have checked my zend code i think it should work but its not working. the value for href does not change